# How to create Django ORM query for Inner Join with Count clause?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, inner-join, django-select-related

I have 2 models named 1.Blogs/Posts 2. PostLike model. I want fetch all blogs with their respected likes counts as well. I have fetch all the blogs data with their likes count in Mysql but I am not aware about the DJANGO ORM query for same

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

status = (('Public','Public'),('Private','Private'))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Public', choices=status)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"id:{self.id},Title:{self.title},Desc:{self.description},Content:{self.content},Owner:{self.owner},Created_at:{self.created_at},Updated_at:{self.updated_at}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"

class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"User:{self.user},Post:{self.user},created:{self.user},"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'PostLikes'
```

after firing following sql query i am able get likes count of blogs:

```
 SELECT posts_post.id, posts_post.title, posts_post.description, posts_post.content, posts_post.owner,posts_post.created_at,posts_post.updated_at,posts_post.status, COUNT(posts_postlike.id) FROM posts_post INNER JOIN posts_postlike ON posts_post.id = posts_postlike.post_id GROUP BY posts_post.id;
```

This is the output I am expecting.

```
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | title  | description  | content  | owner       | created_at                 | updated_at                 | status | COUNT(posts_postlike.id) |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | title1 | description1 | content1 | ashwini@123 | 2023-05-14 16:34:03.991829 | 2023-05-14 16:34:03.991829 | Public |                        4 |
|  2 | title2 | description2 | content2 | ashwini@123 | 2023-05-14 16:35:06.173544 | 2023-05-14 16:35:06.173544 | Public |                        5 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Please someone suggest me Django ORM Query for same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet):

```
from django.db.models import Count

posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count("likes"))
for p in posts:
    # access as attribute
    p.num_likes
```